# How to set a field value before importing nodes using feeds module

Tags: feeds, nodes

I am importing nodes using [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. I have an Entity reference field in my content type which is being generated by Views.

I need the users to select the entity reference field value before starting the import.

My content type is "Student" and the entity reference field is "Course". User Role "Teacher" should import students and select the "course" before importing. (Adding the course ID or Name in the excel sheet is not accepted by my client ).

please suggest.
thanks

Comment: First thoughts: Add the selected reference field value to Session, then create your own [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) plugin to read the Session variable and add to your import set.

Comment: i am looking for an easier way :) .okay if feeds can't do it by default so are there any suggestion for some other module ?